# Hashtag search using Tweepy python

Tags: python, csv, tweepy, import-csv

the code below is to search keywords and store it in csv file, the file name will be whatever hashtag I search. How will I open the csv file (the one saved with the hashtag) in google colab. (python)

```
def search_for_hashtags(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, hashtag_phrase):
    
    #create an authorization for accessing Twitter (aka tell the program we have permission to do what we're doing)
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    #initialize Tweepy API
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    #make the name of the spreadsheet we will write to
    #it will be named whatever we search
    fname = '_'.join(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtag_phrase))

    #open the spreadsheet we will write to
    with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:

        w = csv.writer(file)

        #write header row to spreadsheet
        w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])

        #for each tweet matching our hashtags, write relevant info to the spreadsheet
        #max we can pull is 500,000 tweets a month; I have it set to 100
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag_phrase+' -filter:retweets', \
                                   lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(100):
            w.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), [e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']], tweet.user.followers_count])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you can simply upload that csv (if that is not on collab already) and then open it with `pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')`